# PSA: When using Select2( width: 'resolve' ), box does not resize properly in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, width, jquery-select2

I needed to have a select2 box's width resize after the user selected a value.  I wanted the width to be just wide enough to fit the text of the box.  While I was researching how to do this, I stumbled upon a post that suggested using width: 'resolve' which works perfectly... in everything but Internet Explorer.  I happened to find out that if you set width: function(){}, then it achieves the same result, regardless of browser (at least for the current version of them).  I hope this helps for anyone needing something similar.  My example code is below:

```
$("#MySelect2Box").select2({
    width: function() { /*For some reason, this empty function resizes the box based on the text inside*/ }
});
```

Comment: Please reformulate this as a question, and post the solution as an answer below. See [ask] for help writing questions.

Comment: I don't know how you came to this solution, it's not in the documentation, but it works! Thanks!